# Difference between adjustResize and adjustPan in android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I tried to write a code which is used to re-size the UI components when **soft-keyboard** appears. 
When I use **adjustResize,** it res-size the UI components and at the same time **adjustPan** gave me same output. 
I want to know the difference between them and when to use each component? Which one(adjustPan or adjustResize) is good for resizing UI?

Here is my xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:text="My Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and the menifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.adjustscroll"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.adjustscroll.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: For those working in ReactNative (and probably native Android) - don't forget to rebuild the app when changing the AndroidMainfest file.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

From the [Android Developer Site link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> **"adjustResize"**
>
> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft
> keyboard on screen.
>
> **"adjustPan"**
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
> keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
> so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
> can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
> than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
> get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

according to your comment, use following in your activity manifest

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

Comment: thank you for your nice reply. Now I am having a problem with my UI. I have a edittext and a button at the bottom of my layout. I want to show those above the soft-keyboard when soft-keyboard appears. How can I achieve this. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not working for me. Actually what I wanted: I just want to show Edittext and Button above the soft-keyboard when I try to write something in Edittext field. I tried your solution but not working.

Comment: oops .. it worked for me .. anyways .. is it possible to use scrollview?

Comment: Now I am testing code in eclipse using my symphony phone. I have used scrollview but not working for me.

Comment: it would be more clear if you post the manifest xml .. and the layout xml

Comment: I added my xml and menifest file. Please help me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32696/discussion-between-sharifur-rahman-and-stinepike)

Comment: hi Sharifur please check using adjustResize only .. updated the answer

Comment: adjustResize only provide solution when UI is available for re-sizing but if I put 5 more edittext then it cannot works. Is it possible to show button and edittext above the soft-keyboard when UI is not available to re-size. Actually question is arising when I testing this problem.

Comment: ~"This is generally less desirable than resizing".  Well, not if resizing causes your views to overlap on each other.  Like when you have a tabbed navigation, and a bunch of views in each tab fragment - on some devices adjustResize may cause the views to overlap when the keyboard is shown.  There, unfortunately, you have to set adjustPan if you want to prevent this from happening.

Comment: You should create scrollview as a root layout of your view where keyboard will be shown and replace adjustResize to adjustPan

Comment: @support_ms Why ~"replace adjustResize to adjustPan" is necessary?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I don't remember that. I answered, when I was also working with that kind of task

Comment: I don't think adjustPan is required for ScrollView.

Comment: When I use adjustResize with a Material BottomSheetBehavior layout with a peekHeight of 50dp the keyboard ends up covering the BottomSheetBehaviour , when I use peekHeight of auto it works as desired but the whole BottomSheetBehavior layout is shown which is not the desired effect I want.

When using adjustPan the effect is as desired but part of the BottomSheetBehavior layout is hidded under the keyboard. How can I fix it? I have researched a lot of question but still no solution.

Answer (score 65):

I was also a bit confused between adjustResize and adjustPan when I was a beginner. The definitions given above are correct.
**AdjustResize :** Main activity's content is resized to make room for soft input i.e keyboard
 
**AdjustPan :** Instead of resizing overall contents of the window, it only pans the content so that the user can always see what is he typing
**AdjustNothing :** As the name suggests nothing is resized or panned. Keyboard is opened as it is irrespective of whether it is hiding the contents or not.
 
I have a created a example for better understanding
Below is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Type Here"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin70dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin70dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin70dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is the design view of the xml**
[image: original view]

**AdjustResize Example below:**
[image: adjustResize example]

**AdjustPan Example below:**
[image: adjustPan example]

**AdjustNothing Example below:**
[image: adjustNothing example]

Answer (score 53):

**adjustResize** = resize the page content

**adjustPan** = move page content without resizing page content

Comment: `adjustResize` and I must reinstall the app to get it work (work = no overlap), am I the only one ?

Answer (score 26):

Thanks @Nadeem for the inspiration.

This may demonstrate the difference more intuitively.

**When the keyboard is not showing:**

[image: noKeyboard]

**When the soft keyboard shows**

[image: Compare differences]

On my simulator, **adjustUnspecified** has the same result with **adjustPan**.

Here is the layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- This layout takes all the reset of the screen -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_colors"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/et_input_field"
        >
        <!-- Divide the layout into 3 different colors -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_input_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thing's much easier with illustration, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

As [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) says also keep in mind the correct value combination:

> The setting must be one of the values listed in the following table,
>   or a combination of one "state..." value plus one "adjust..." value.
>   Setting multiple values in either group — multiple "state..." values,
>   for example — has undefined results. Individual values are separated
>   by a vertical bar (|). For example:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >
```

Comment: not working , my screen is going behind the soft input

Answer (score 8):

**Solution:**

You can use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

For your current activity,
and use

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in `styles or rootLayout`.