# Positioning EditText Above Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have got an `EditText` looking like this (with "bottom gravity"):

[image]

When I press the `EditText`, the keyboard shows up and I can't see anymore what I'm typing (because the EditText is now behind the keyboard, on the bottom). How could I move the `EditText` automatically just above the keyboard, when it has been pressed?

At the end, it would be good if it would look like this:

[image]

**My Code:**

```
// LINEAR LAYOUT
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
setContentView(layout);
// TEXTVIEW
layout.addView(tv);
// EDITTEXT
et.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
et.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
                        et.setLayoutParams(params); // SOMETHING LIKE ONTOUCH -> MOVE UPWARDS
                        layout.addView(et);
```

Comment: By default android automatically do for you.

Comment: It's been answered, like here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In your Manifest file add the following code for this particular activity

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) doc for more info.

Comment: If you get an activity from code you can also set it like this:
`activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

Answer (score 11):

use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

in your Manifest file. 
See [developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for your reference

Answer (score 4):

It happens sometimes that setting activity in manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

not working with scrolling views containing `EditText`.

After research I figured out 
that to work in some cases parent layout has to be set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. Then native functionality of scrolling `EditText` above scrollbar working like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Simply setting **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"** in the layout xml worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Could you explain where you set this, as the OP is not showing .xml. Do you have an edit to the shown code that could fix OP's problem?