# Keyboard with one input line above

Tags: android, keyboard

How can i call this keyboard on android?

Features: Landscape, one line input above.

[image]

Saw this in unity app and developer said it's native, but searching in Google and SO not helped.

Comment: See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858987/positioning-edittext-above-keyboard) and Then [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape).

Comment: Its not working in my case, don't know why. For first click screen scrolls to show edit text on top of keyboard. End editing and click again on edit text - keyboard appears, but screen not scrolled.