# Multiline EditText is half hidden when the soft keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-edittext

I have the following code that is inside a **ScrollView** and the **SoftInput.AdjustResize** setting, but when the keyboard is shown, it hides **half** of the **EditText**. Also, when a new line is added, all the rows above the cursor are shown.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:minHeight="10dp"
    android:maxLines="6"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:cursorVisible="true"/>
```

**Do you know a way in which I can have the whole EditText displayed?**

Also, an implementation without the **ScrollView** and with **SoftInput.AdjustPan** was tested, and the result is the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858987/positioning-edittext-above-keyboard

Comment: as stated in the description, I already tried the AdjustPan option. It works ok for single line EditText but with multiline not.

Comment: try to use `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` in edittext

Comment: It does not work, the displayed part is just the first row. It seems that the system behaves differently on the multiline.

Comment: @UsamaAltaf workaround that worked was to set gravity bottom and that way the cursor will be on the second row and the entire EditText is visible. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **workaround fix** is to set gravity bottom and that way the cursor will be on the second row and the entire EditText is visible.