# Android keyboard hides LinerLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an EditText and a button capsuled in a LinearLayout but on typing on the EditText, the keyboard on android hides the layout in spite of specifying

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

and

```
       <activity
        android:name=".postNavigator"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_post_navigator"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">

    </activity>
```

[image: Keyboard hides the EditText]

my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dailyspring.rejo.cpray.postNavigator">

<!--<ImageView-->
<!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
<!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
<!--android:scaleType="centerCrop"-->
<!--android:src="@drawable/back_blur" />-->

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <com.github.leonardoxh.customfont.FontText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
            android:text="Post Title"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:font="Roboto-Thin" />
        <com.github.leonardoxh.customfont.FontText
            android:id="@+id/authorName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
            android:text="Author"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            app:font="Roboto-Thin" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                android:text="DescriptionDescription Description Description DescriptionDescription Description Description Description Description Descriptionescription sDescripti Description Description Description Description Description Description Descriptionescription sDescripti Description Description Description Description Description Description Description" />
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:id="@+id/loadingProgressBar"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15sp">

                    <com.github.leonardoxh.customfont.FontText
                        android:id="@+id/commentTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                        android:text="Comments"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        app:font="Roboto-Thin" />


                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listcomments"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:divider="@null"
                        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_nobg"
                        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                        android:stackFromBottom="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/commentText"

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:hint="  add comment"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
                <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton

                    android:layout_width="53dp"
                    android:layout_height="53dp"
                    android:id="@+id/pickImage"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_48dp"
                    app:cb_color="#99CC00"
                    app:cb_pressedRingWidth="5dip" />

            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried adjusting the  android:layout_weight and adjusting the margins and padding but nothing helps. How can i solve this ?

Comment: Did you read it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android ?

Comment: yeah. specifying any one doesn't help. still hides the layout

Answer (score 0):

[android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) couldn't be something OR something, you should set here only one value. In your case I think you need adjustPan.

Btw, why are you using all that weight? It some mess in your layout. Your UI could be implemented just with simple vertically oriented LinearLayout. Also TextView inside ScrollView? Use maxLines param.

Comment: @RejoChandran Complitly relayout your UI, as I suggested and everything would be ok.

Comment: I guess the Layouts need to be worked again; Anyways android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" should push all the elements off the screen regardless of the alignment...

Answer (score -1):

Use `windowSoftInputMode`, like this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```