# How to specify spaces between android elements from graphical layout

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, layout, android-layout-weight

I have created a layout that is showing perfect result on graphical layout, but when i launch the application is Emulator its giving very weird look.

[image]

**Emulator**

[image]

I have tried `margin` and `Padding`  both , but still i am not getting desired output in the emulator.

The following is my `xml` file. Everything is wrap in `relativeLayout` tag

**XML File**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/successMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Launch Complain"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50pt"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Send Message" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Complain"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtShopName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/userMessage"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userMessage"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Shop Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Comment: I notice that there are warnings in your first screenshot. What are they saying?

Comment: Please paste all your layout code. I cant see parent. It is Relative Layout or what?

Comment: warning says, Hardcoded string, Should use @String resource

Comment: Yes, its all in `relativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

The placement of your views is currently largely based on the position relative to the center of the screen. What you need is placing your Views relative to each other.

Use the android:layout_below="@+id/item_ID" to place a view below another view, like this:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/successMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Launch Complain"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50pt"
         />

  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtShopName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/successMessage"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Shop Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtShopName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Complain"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userMessage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Send Message" />
```

Comment: Thanks , let me try this

Comment: i have added the above mentioned code, but nothing is changed..I am still getting the same result in emulator

Comment: Did you remove the centerVertical parts? I added an example where I removed the code that affected vertical alignment.

Comment: Thanks, this added the space..but all the elements are messed up..I  have uploaded the image..Kindly check  http://s27.postimg.org/ocj3jduw3/space_Added.png

Comment: Add this to the txtShopName layout: android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Answer (score 0):

This is not a graphical issue, it happens due to keyboard focusing to "EditText- complain". For solving this you need to mane in Manifest file. Try this

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Your Activity"           
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"          
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```

Here   **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** to mange your issue.
[For more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android)