# Android Keyboard - android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Tags: android, cordova, android-layout, ionic-framework

I know there is heaps on here related to the virtual keyboard in Android, but I just cant seem to figure out how to achieve a solution to my problem.

For those that are not familiar with `AdjustPan` and `AdjustResize` you can check out what they are/do here - [Difference between adjustResize and adjustPan in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android#answer-17410528)

What I am trying to achieve is the `AdjustPan` result in which my webview is not resized, but scrolls to the input box instead as I have submit/cancel buttons that are `position:absolute` to the bottom of the screen. When I use the `AdjustPan` setting, the keyboard opens up but covers my input and doesn't scroll the webview to the input.

On the other hand when I use the `AdjustResize` option, the `position:absolute` buttons from the footer cover the last few inputs as there is quite a lot of content to fit in half the screen size.

Currently my Activity looks like this

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

I am trying to avoid the Javascript listener solutions as they seem a bit hackery and from my experience usually don't provide a seamless look and feel.

Comment: I'm facing the same thing. Were you able to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. OPTION 1

Add a blank layout with height approximately equal to the height of keypad. Move the webview and the blank layout into a ScrollView and disable the webviews scroll.

2. OPTION 2

Append a few line breaks to the web content that is loaded in the webview.