# Android keyboard lift tablayout to top?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity. This activity's layout has one ViewPager. This viewpager has five fragment by code. And I have five icons at the bottom of screen. They are located in tablayout.

Come to main point, When I open keyboard, the keyboard lift tablayout to top? How can solve it ?

**I tried the ways below  :**

- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
- android:isScrollContainer="false"
- android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

**EDIT :** 
I updated my layout. Any ideas for this problem so far ?

**activity_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activityRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:transitionGroup="false"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_background"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabText" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
        <include
            layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` so tablayout will not lift to top. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/4628611)

Answer (score 0):

### The short answer

You can't set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`
 this combination is illegal as stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft):

> Setting multiple values in either group — multiple "state..." values, for example — has undefined results

Instead just set it to pan `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

### Some explanation

If the soft keyboard alters your layout it means that either `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified"` were set. For the latter case the system will deciede automatically if to pan or resize, it will resize if it finds any views that can be scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer is absolutely right.

> You can't set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`, this combination is illegal.

Instead just set it to pan `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` it will not move `TabLayout` to top. But there is one more thing I would like to add. **adjustPan** and **adjustResize** work as expected only when you have set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your root layout.

So your layout should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activityRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    // Your Layout

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There's no need for fitssystemwindow.  True is the default.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes it is true by default. But to avoid any confusion in such conditions, I would prefer defining it explicitly in case it is being inherited from somewhere or missed unintentionally.