# Make keyboard do not push up view to top Android

Tags: android

First, I apologize for English proficiency
    I'm developing a project and i have problem. This is my keyboard will push view when it appear, I don't want this! How to make it. Thank you. This is my code`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNoPhoto"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/colorBackGroundInfoMain"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="This place don't have any photos yet"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <com.libreteam.beliat.common.ClickableViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pageImageAddPlace"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"></com.libreteam.beliat.common.ClickableViewPager>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvCountImage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCountImage"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" />


                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorItemMenuNoClick"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imgUpLoad"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_upload" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_trash" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorRoundSignUp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Place Information"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonLogInFB"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tvPlaceName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_edit_18"
                    android:hint="Place Name"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorBackGroundInfoMain"></View>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tvShortDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_edit_18"
                    android:hint="Short Description"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorBackGroundInfoMain"></View>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_edit_18"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorRoundSignUp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Place Category"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonLogInFB"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvChooseCategory"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_edit_18"
                    android:hint="Choose a category for place"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorRoundSignUp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Location on the map"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonLogInFB"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp">
                    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:id="@+id/mMap"
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

                    <View
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorItemMenuNoClick"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Change location on the map"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </RelativeLayout>




            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnSavePlace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorButtonSignUp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Save place"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_pickImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8C000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFromCamera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorBackGroundInfo"
                android:text="@string/from_camera"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFromGallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/colorBackGroundInfo"
                android:text="@string/from_gallery"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/colorBackGroundInfo"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: U mean android key board is hiding your view by pushing it to top ?

Comment: Thanks, I want keyboard do not push btnSavePlace to top keyboard but btnSavePlace always at the bottom of the screen!

Comment: Ok see my answer and i will also try your code after sometime and give u solution @HangThanh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is situation certain times when you want your all content reachable or sometimes you don't want it like in your case Android has one property for keyboard adjustments,you can simply do it by changing it in AndroidMenifest file It is windowsSoftInputMode.
maybe it is right now adjustpan or adjustResize so it forces the content all the way up.
if you want nothing then do not set this property at all so it will stick to the default behavior, Want more to learn about it Check below links for depth understanding, Thanks.

Developer Documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft 
Similar links 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7509285/5476209  
 and 
[Difference between adjustResize and adjustPan in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android)

Comment: sorry, but I do not have enough reputation! :(