# React-native: How to control what keyboard pushes up

Tags: react-native

The structure of the app is fairly simple: A searchbar, a listview and react-native-tabs at the bottom. The problem: If I click on the searchbar on Android it pushes the whole app up, so I see the tabs directly over the keyboard. But on iOS the keyboard overlays the whole app, without pushing anything up. Is there any way to control that?
I'm happy to share code / screenshots if the question isn't clear.
Thanks

edit:

```js
<View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2'}}>
    <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderSearchResults.bind(this)}
        style={styles.listView}/>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.addQuestionBar}
        behavior={'position'}>
        <Text>
            Don't see your question?
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>
                Add it
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

Comment: I have tried adding the KeyboardAvoidingView component in numerous places with my ListView and I cannot get it to work. This component works great with ScrollViews as well and is supposed to work with ListView, but I get stranger rendering problems with it: https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: If you wrap the ListView with the KeyboardAvoidingView the avoiding works, but scrolling stops working :s

Comment: I am facing the same issue.Did you find the solution? @dv3

Comment: @dhrumil.m not really no, that's why I never accepted an answer here. But my react-native days are gone now... I'm not up to date

Comment: Okay. Thanks anyway @dv3

Comment: Do we have any solution for this in 2021 ??

Comment: @yanky_cranky sorry I'm not working with RN anymore, but there are "newer" solutions below

Answer (score 163):

Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your manifest file, and it will work as you expect.

E.g.

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  ...
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    ...
  </activity>
  ...
</application>
```

Comment: I had to close the bundle window and re-run `react-native run-android`, after setting 'adjustPan'.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I thought I needed KeyboardAvoidingView, but this solution works perfect.

Comment: Setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` disables scrolling for me. The keyboard covers some components, and I can not see them, nor can I scroll the screen

Comment: Thank you so much, adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" will sort everything

Comment: NO! Do not do this unless you know exactly what it's doing. I put this in my app to solve some problem and then lost a whole day trying to make my top app bar not be pushed out (panned) out of the screen! Use"adjustResize". Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/4345461 .

Comment: I use `adjustResize` and i have to reinstall once to get my adjustment done, otherwise it overlap my forms.

Comment: Is there a way to do the reverse of this for iOS? I want the iOS keyboard to push up the layout like android

Comment: `adjustPan` worked for me. 
(Please note you need to `./gradlew clean` in your android folder and then run `npx react-native run-android` to see the effect)

Answer (score 73):

**For those using Expo**

@J KW's answer is correct but if you're using Expo you will have to implement it differently.

Expo uses different configuration terms. In your app.json you have to set the configuration key
`"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode":"pan"` in your android object.
Your file might look something like:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App",
    ...
    "android":{"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"},
    ...
  }
}
```

Note: If you are receiving a "should NOT have additional property" error, it's likely because you don't have the updated Expo SDK (v.038). Please [update your Expo version](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-38-is-now-available-ab6cd30ca2ee).

Documentation: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/

Comment: For those interested, the documentation is [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#softwarekeyboardlayoutmode) and you can also see the [PR](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/8842)

Comment: this still isnt working for me...i can still see a white background when i open and close the keyboard? can you tell me how to fix this pls?

Comment: Make sure you restart the Expo CLI after this change as the config is only read during startup.

Answer (score 15):

There is new Component called **KeyboardAvoidingView** from React Native not documented yet but i already use it in my project and its very useful

Code Example:

```js
'use strict'
import { ... , KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native'

class Test extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      behavior: 'position' 
      // there is three ways to adjust (position , height , padding ) 
    }
  }
    


  render(){
    return (
        <View>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={this.state.behavior}>
            <TextInput
              style={style.PhoneNumberInput}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
              value={this.state.text}
              />
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    )
  }

}


module.exports = Test
```

and for more details you can check **[KeyboardAvoidingViewExample](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a2fb703bbb988038323c55b29b40e8f5ff52966d/Examples/UIExplorer/js/KeyboardAvoidingViewExample.js)**

EDIT:

Sorry i just got the wrong idea from the question i think what you are trying to do is stop the android keyboard from pushing the application up here is component that allow you to choose between (Pan, Resize, Nothing) in android

**[react-native-android-keyboard-adjust](https://github.com/zubricky/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust)**

Comment: ah no way this is genius...how do I know which RN version this requires?

Comment: @dv3 its in react native since v0.29 and above but it will be official i think on 33.0 , you can use it now instead.

Comment: Lol I've no idea how I could debug this since it's under the keyboard. I want the tabs to remain under the keyboard, but right over the keyboard I want to display a simple "add button". behaviour={'position'} doesn't achieve this though... :-/

Comment: @dv3 okay put the close component under the inputText and use padding

Comment: hm, thanks, but I have the TextInput in the NavigationBar, in the view I display the results... I've inserted some code in the question

Answer (score 2):

### Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize".`

KeyboardAvoidingView and other keyboard-related components don't work quite well if you have "adjustPan" set for your `android:windowSoftInputMode` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Instead, you should use "adjustResize" and have a wonderful life.

I had "adjustPan" and tried using KeyboardAvoidingView and KeyboardAwareScrollView... nothing worked.

Now, with "adjustResize", i'm not using any keyboard-related component and my android app works. (I might have to use KeyboardAvoiding view on iOS, but it will work out of the box.)

Comment: Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/
 • Field: android.softwareKeyboardLayoutMode - should be equal to one of the allowed values.

Comment: @Cory Looks like you mistyped the value of `softwareKeyboardLayoutMode`.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#softwarekeyboardlayoutmode
Check that link out. It says that the possible values for `android.softwareKeyboardLayoutMode` are only "resize" and "pan".

Answer (score 0):

@binkie's answer worked for my expo (Version 44.0.0) app with a slight change.
In app.json,

```
"android":{"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"}
```

In the screen, margin bottom value equal to height of the bottom tab like so

```
<ScrollView mb="70px">...</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

****1) modify the AndroidMainfest.xml in
android/src/main/AndroidMainfest.xml   
u can solve the issue by changing the

```
       $ android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize";
                       to  
       $ android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan";


          the problem will be resolvede****
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while React Native - Javascript, `SafeAreaView` and `ScrollView` fix the problem

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView  > 
      <View style={styles.body}>
....

 container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white' 
  },
```