# ImageBackground moving after pressing the InputText

Tags: react-native

Hello I just started to use React Native and I want to use an image as background but when press to an input text the image moves a little bit up and I want to be fixed.

```
const backgroundImage = './assets/background-blur.jpg'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <ImageBackground source={require(backgroundImage)} style={style.background}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <SearchInput />
                </ScrollView>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    )
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }
})
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try `backgroundAttachment: fixed`

Comment: @ravibagul91 it tells me is not a valid style property :(

Comment: @JonathanGómez welcome to stackoverflow.You may be looking for this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344140/react-native-how-to-control-what-keyboard-pushes-up