# Keyboard changes all components placement in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I created an AuthForm component that I use for a sign up and sign in screen after styling the screen I noticed every time I click on the keyboard to type some input everything changes its original placement and some components overlay others and it turns into a mess, how can I fix this?

Here is the code i used

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { Text, Button, Input } from "react-native-elements";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
import Spacer from "./Spacer";

const AuthForm = ({
  headerText,
  errorMessage,
  onSubmit,
  submitButtonText,
  subText,
}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Spacer>
        <Text style={styles.Text1}>{headerText}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.Text2}>{subText}</Text>
      </Spacer>
      <View style={styles.Input}>
        <Input
          style={styles.Input}
          placeholder="Your email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={setEmail}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          leftIcon={<Icon name="email" size={20} color="#B3C1B3" />}
        />
        <Input
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Your password"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={setPassword}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          leftIcon={<Icon name="lock" size={20} color="#B3C1B3" />}
        />
      </View>
      {errorMessage ? (
        <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{errorMessage}</Text>
      ) : null}

      <Spacer>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress={() => onSubmit({ email, password })}
        >
          <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>{submitButtonText}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Spacer>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    //justifyContent: "center",
  },
  errorMessage: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "red",
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginTop: 15,
    top: "35%",
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    color: "#e8c0c8",
    width: "45%",
    height: "25%",
    backgroundColor: "#fdc2e6",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 15,
    top: "150%",
    left: "30%",
  },
  ButtonText: {
    color: "#FFFF",
  },
  Text1: {
    top: "420%",
    left: "15%",
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "#ffffff",
  },
  Text2: {
    top: "420%",
    left: "15%",
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#d9d9d9",
  },
  Input: {
    top: "40%",
    width: "70%",
    left: "15%",
  },
});

export default AuthForm;
```

Comment: Can you remove the reactjs tag? It should not be added

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update June 29, 2020. EXPO SDK 38 is out and this setting is available on `app.json`**

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...your app.json expo config,
    "android": {
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"
    }
  }
}
```

Refer to the content in expo blog

> New android.softwareKeyboardLayoutMode app.json key One tricky part of
> building forms in mobile apps is that developers need to ensure that
> the on-screen “software keyboard” doesn’t obscure the focused form
> element. Android lets you pick how you want this to be handled: you
> can resize the entire window so nothing will be drawn under the
> keyboard, or you can pan the window so the content is not underneath
> it. The native property that lets you control this is
> android:windowSoftInputMode .
>
> In the past, all Expo apps have been configured to use the resize
> mode, but some developers have found this to be problematic for their
> apps because UI elements such as tab bars will be pushed up above the
> keyboard when it is enabled. If you would prefer to use the pan mode,
> you can now set the layout mode directly with
> android.softwareKeyboardLayoutMode in your app configuration. Find the
> key in the "android" section of "Configuration with app.json".

Reference about this setting: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/#android

---

**Answer before Expo 38**

I think you may observed this problem on Android but not on iOS?

In that case, you will have to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your manifest file

E.g.

```xml
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  ...
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    ...
  </activity>
  ...
</application>
```

Comment: am using an android emulator yes but i can't tell if i have the same problem on ios too since am on windows and dont own an iphone

Comment: if it looks like this https://snack.expo.io/@gie3d/frisky-pudding ?. You may try the solution above. It may solve your problem (android keyboard won't push the whole screen up) or this answer may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344140/react-native-how-to-control-what-keyboard-pushes-up

Comment: is there a way to modify my AndroidManifest.xml when using expo ?

Comment: Sad but true, as far as i know, no... you can modify it after eject from expo.

Comment: This setting is available now in Expo SDK 38. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. 
After 2 hours of researchs, you fixed my issue with 1 line in 1 file.

Comment: Life saver! work in 2022

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a component named KeyboardAvoidingView.
Here is the link to the official documentation with an example of use : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Comment: the keyboardAvoidingView pushed everything to the top of the screen and squashed it together even giving it a flex of 1 did not seem to solve the problem

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that you are positioning your elements using percentages when you could simply use flex elements and use dp (marginTop: 20) for the margin or padding that you would want.

Comment: i only used percentage so that can achieve a similar look on different screen sizes is i will use px instead hopefully it will solve the problem