# Keyboard pushing everything up in React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, ecmascript-2016

I have a simple auth form in my react-native app, but everytime the software keyboard appears, whole screen moves up and squishes everything together. I am desperate and unable to do anything about it, I tried to style with percentages, flex, custom libraries but the effect is always the same. In other question I found a solution where you need to edit Android manifest, but I would like to avoid that. I just need the keyboard to cover everything on the bottom of the screen instead of moving everything above.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can wrap your content within a ScollView and set its props like this: `style={{flex: 1}} contentContainerStyle={{minHeight: '100%'}}`

Comment: This works partialy, but there is another problem, when I write something into the input (that means my local state changes) it looks like the style of initial render is overwritten. Looks like the height is now calculated from the space without the keyboard and everything squshes again.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your layout in a Scrollview with style={{flex: 1}}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the KeyBoardAvoidingView component? [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview)

Comment: Actualy I did, but to my understanding it does the opposite of what I want. I dont want anything to move, I just want the keyboard to render over the content. Or maybe I got it wrong from the docs?

Comment: Try this: keyboardVerticalOffset={-500} behavior="padding", If it doesn't work then definitely stick with the manifest change of adjustNothing.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in AndroidManifest.xml worked perfect for me. I found this solution in this question [React-native: How to control what keyboard pushes up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344140/react-native-how-to-control-what-keyboard-pushes-up)