# How to NOT move view when keyboard pops up

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard

My app dynamically creates a `TextInput` and focuses it when the user presses a button. When this happens, the keyboard pops up and the surrounding view **moves upward** slightly. I do not want this to happen. How do I achieve this?

Comment: you may have wrapped your views in keyboardAvoidingView i suppose

Comment: @GauravRoy Sadly I haven't. I do not understand why the view is moving.

Comment: Self answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344140/react-native-how-to-control-what-keyboard-pushes-up this worked for me