# How can we display keyboard properly when TextField in Android Titanium gains focus?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building an app with Appcelerator (for Android system).
I'm building a View with some TextField, Label etc.

Now if I try to click on one of these TextField, (correctly) I can see the Keyboard of the smartphone.
If I try to click of the end of this TextField, I can see the Keyboard but it hides the TextField and I can't see the text that I digit.

This is the code

```
<Window id="registry_edit_window" onClose="cleanup">
    
    
    <View id="outer_container">
        
        <View id="close_button">
                <!-- <Label id="close_button_label" text="X" />  -->
                <ImageView id="close_icon" image="/images/new_icons/close_icon_white.png"></ImageView>
        </View> <!-- end close_button -->
        
        
        
        <View class="inner_container">
        
        
            <!-- title -->
            <Label id="title" />
            
        
        
            <ScrollView id="scrollForm">
                
                    <View id="name_row" class="row_item">
                        <Label id="name_label" class="label" text="" />
                        <TextField id="name_field" class="field" />
                    </View>
                    
                    <View id="surname_row" class="row_item">
                    <Label id="surname_label" class="label" text="" />
                    <TextField id="surname_field" class="field" />
                </View>
                
                <View id="birthdate_row" class="row_item">
                    <Label id="birthdate_label" class="label" text="" />
                    <TextField id="birthdate_field" class="field" editable="false" />
                </View>
                
                <View id="address_row" class="row_item">
                    <Label id="address_label" class="label" text="" />                  
                    <TextField id="address_field" class="field" />
                </View>
                
                <View id="country_row" class="row_item">
                    <Label id="country_label" class="label" text="" />                  
                    <TextField id="country_field" class="field" />
                </View>
                
                <View id="phone_row" class="row_item">
                    <Label id="phone_label" class="label" text="" />            
                    <TextField id="phone_field" class="field" />
                </View>
                
                <View id="phone_emergency_row" class="row_item">
                    <Label id="phone_emergency_label" class="label" text="" />              
                    <TextField id="phone_emergency_field" class="field" />
                </View>
                
                <View id="notes_row" class="row_item" height="Titanium.UI.SIZE">
                    <Label id="notes_label" class="label" text="" />                
                    <TextArea id="notes_area" class="text_area" />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            
        
            
            <View id="buttons_section">
                
                <View id="save_button" class="custom_button">
                    <ImageView id="save_icon" image="/images/new_icons/save_icon_white.png" class="button_icon"></ImageView>
                    <Label id="save_label" class="custom_button_label" text=""></Label>
                </View>
                
            </View>
        
        
    </View> <!-- end inner_container -->
    </View> <!-- end outer_container -->
</Window>
```

how can I fixed it?

[image]

As you can see, in this first picture, I can see any TextField.

[image]

As you can see, I have click on the last of TextField but I can't see it.

Comment: Why don't you use scrollView.

Comment: Instead of "<View class="container">  " I should to use ScrollView?

Comment: where are the text-fields in your Alloy code? and what is the color value of your text-fields...? as per your second screenshot, it looks like your text-fields have **color='white'**

Comment: It seems nothing wrong with the keyboard and scrolling because you can see that ***teal colored cursor*** which means that your keyboard is shown up correctly, only you have a white color for that text-field.

Comment: @PrashantSaini sorry I have for error copy other file, I have just edit my first post

Comment: @bircastri what's the value of **id="phone_emergency_field" class="field"**.

what's the color value of this text-field?

Answer (score 0):

apply the soft input adjust pan on your android window, you can even do this globally through the app.tss file

```
"Window[platform=android]": {
    windowSoftInputMode: Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
}
```

Comment: I have use your code in my app.tss file but this code not fixed my problem

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android

Comment: I don't have found a solution. To fixed my Problem, I have insert a global View under ScrollView so I have set the height of this global view as "200%" so I can scroll di view if I have the Keyboard open.

Comment: If you can create a gist with a full controller js xml and tss files, i'll try  to give it a look indepth