# android studio: when the keyboard pops up the layout jumbles

Tags: android, layout, keyboard

this is the layout before keyboard pops up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kUO3.png)

and this is it after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvIaf.png)

How can I stop this jumbling of the layout when user clicks on textEdit?

Here is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.aymanharake.firstproject.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:text="How old are you?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/GirlSays"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:text="Guess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Response:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RequestResponse"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Person says:"
        android:id="@+id/GirlSays"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Have a better response?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:maxLines = "5"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp" />

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:text="Write it here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button

        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/GirlSays"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp" />

    <Button

        android:text="Request&#10;response"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RequestResponse"
        android:layout_below="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your xml file is not visible..........

Comment: put your xml here to help you.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your manifest inside activity tag

Comment: use adjustpan for this activity in your android manifest file. refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android) also [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest add below line,

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

For more info [AdjustPan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/3782085)