# when keyboard open webview move to up in android?

Tags: android, webview, keyboard

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_view">

    <im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView>

</ScrollView>
```

How to move textfield up from webview when keyboard appears?

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, in <activity> tag, add this:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

check this for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/2709298