# Why FAB set under CardView with layout_anchorGravity

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/activity_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_authentication_container"
                    style="@style/CardView"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/button_authentication"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp">
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/float_button_authenticate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/gamepad"
                    app:fabSize="mini"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/card_authentication_container"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I try to set floating action button on CardView with app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal", it set under CardView.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO8Vd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your:

```
app:cardElevation="10dp"
```

Since you `CardView` elevation will be greater than the one in your `FloatingActionButton`, it will always appear behind.

Explanation: from the [documentation](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html):

> Elevation is the relative distance between two surfaces along the
>   z-axis.

So in terms of the z-axis, your `CardView` is in a much higher place (10dp) than your FAB (since you didn't define any elevation value it will use the default which is 0dp).

---

**Solution:**
Set an elevation in your FAB with the value **10dp or greater**.

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/float_button_authenticate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gamepad"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/card_authentication_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
```

---

**Tip:** don't use 10dp for your card elevation. Use the recommended value in the [material specification](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#default-elevations) which is 1dp.

Comment: This is related to your `windowSoftInputMode`. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/1574250

Comment: @yasser_kh If that fixed your issue, please mark this answer has it correct one so it can helper others :)