# Show Custom Toolbar while Scrolling Screen with Keyboard

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Please read the question carefully before any action,

I am using the custom toolbar in my android application with one image, one button, and title.

Now below that, I have a full screen with edit texts and text views and buttons. While I am trying to fill data and keyboard is open at that time while I am scroll down my screen upside, it hides toolbar also, even toolbar is outside of scroll.

I have taken scrollbar inside the body view, not for the whole screen, but then also while I am scrolling it hides the toolbar.

Comment: I post it my answer please have a look at it.

Comment: I have used all properties of that like adjustResize, adjustPanel and all, but useless

Comment: can you share your XML and code?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in manifest file it may work.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in your activity tag in Manifest file

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on the screen.

Moreover, you can find the detail about it here official [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

Also, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android)

Hope it will be helpful to you.