# How to avoid Toolbar Hide when EditTexts get focused

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Please find the xml Layout below

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_common"/>
    

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/chatRecycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appbarlayout"
                android:background="@color/light_grey"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/msgEt"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".9"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="send"/>
            </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: image1]

[[image: image2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkhrQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `AdjustPan` like `android:windowSoftInputMode="AdjustPan"` or  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`

---

You should use `adjustResize` there

---

see [Difference between adjustResize and adjustPan in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android) for understand android:windowSoftInputMode

Comment: after changing adjust resize also not changed

Comment: can you please use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on the root RelativeLayout?

Comment: after fitssystemwindow also not affected

Comment: do you change change `android:windowSoftInputMode` in your java class?

Comment: I did but no change

Comment: can you please share what you did in your java class?