# Keyboard hides inputs - Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material, ionic4, ionic-native

Ionic 6 (Angular) hides input when keyboard shows.  What happens is that when I focus on an input the keyboard lifts up and covers the selected input.  Is there a way to avoid this behavior by making it auto-scroll until the keyboard is positioned below the selected input?

[INPUT/KEYBOARD IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsRTY.jpg)

Comment: Are you using full screen plugin?

Comment: you can simply use a "margin" in your page. If you want you make the margin using only `[style.margin-bottom]="onFocus?'20rem':null"` and in each input in (focus)/(blur)change the property onFocus to true/false -or use a directive

Comment: I was facing the same issue in my ionic app (with Capacitor). I resolved the issue by just installing the Keyboard plugin. That's right, I didn't even have to use the plugin anywhere, I just had to install it & it did the trick.
I don't why it's like that but for me, it only works when I have the plugin installed even if I'm not using it to get different behaviour.
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/keyboard#install

Comment: if using capacitor check this link https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/issues/118#issuecomment-1049300493

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **cordova**, you can set what happens to the UI when soft-keyboard appears ('[adjustResize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/10602679)' or '[adjustPan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/10602679)').

For that, inside **`config.xml`**, add an `<edit-config>` tag in `<platform name="android">`

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']" mode="merge">
        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
</edit-config>
```

Make sure to add android-res namespace in `<widget>` tag :

```
<widget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" .....>
```

**For Capacitor apps:**

Use Keyboard API's [setResizeMode()](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/keyboard#setresizemode) method for adjusting the UI when keyboard appears.

In app.component.ts:

```
import { Plugins, KeyboardInfo } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Keyboard } = Plugins;

...

Keyboard.setResizeMode({mode:'ionic'});
```

For other suported modes, checkout https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/keyboard#keyboard-configuration-ios-only

Comment: import Plugins is deprecated and Capacitor 3 now uses modulated plugins so they're all independent of each other.
In this case you can simply import Keyboard directly, like so:
import { Keyboard } from '@capacitor/keyboard';

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use a "margin" in your page.

If you want you make the margin using only `[style.margin-bottom]="onFocus?'20rem':null"` and in each input in (focus)/(blur)change the property onFocus to true/false. To make this "easy", you can use a directive, the directive make a next to a Subject of a service, and in the main component you subscribe to this subject. Well, in code:

The service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuxService {

  focusSubject:Subject<boolean>=new Subject<boolean>()
  constructor() { }
}
```

The directive: (see the "selector" of the directive, is applied to all the inputs else checkbox)

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input:not([type="checkbox])'
})
export class OnFocusDirective {
  @HostListener('focus')
  _() {
    this.auxService.focusSubject.next(true)
 }
  @HostListener('blur')
  __() {
    this.auxService.focusSubject.next(false)
 }
  constructor(private auxService:AuxService) { }
}
```

The main-component:

```
export class AppComponent{
  onFocus$=this.auxService.focusSubject

  constructor(private auxService:AuxService) { }
}
```

And its .html

```
<div [style.margin-bottom]="(onFocus$|async)?'20rem':null">
    <p>
        Start editing to see some magic happen :)
    </p>
    <input>
</div>
```

[The stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vcjnbw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I think that should work

Comment: This looks promising but cannot test this in the stackblitz from my device, the link does not open, as recommended by someone, I worked around this through a fixed height dummy control below at the end of the page allowing users to scroll