# react native avoid scrollview/flatlist shrinking while keyboard is open

Tags: react-native

In my react native app, I have a header with a search option and a body with content which is a flatlist and a footer. The flatlist is shrinking when the keyboard is active and my footer is showing above the keyboard.

I don't want to shrink flatlist while the keyboard is active or don't want to show the footer while the keyboard is active. how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use KeyboardAvoidingView from react-native.
Please check your android manifest it should have

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

something like this(please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android))

Comment: "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode":"pan" solved the issue in my expo project, thanks for your time.