# How to keep original layout when click show softkey in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout, android-softkeyboard

After I click edit text to show soft key, layout banner at bottom position layout moved up.
I want to keep origin layout after click show key board in android

Comment: Consider including the applicable HTML, script or code with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this attribute to your Activity in AndoridManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Just like below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` or `android:windowsSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in you manifest file.
You can choose one of them which is most preferable to your activity layout.
For more details you can refer this answer. [adjustPan or adjustResize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/9793289)

Please accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution.